# yahoo pipes: regex not working at all

Tags: regex, rss, pipe, yahoo

All I want is to have large images on my CNN feed instead of the small thumbnails. This should be pretty straight forward.

From CNN you get this ending in RSS feeds (small thumb): top-tease.jpg
And this in the full article: horizontal-gallery.jpg

Look at the URLs, this should be an easy replace. But regex isn't working at all. Even when I try something crazy like replace .JPG with .7Z (which should break all images). Nothing works.

Here's my feed: http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=d8562ff09578abb0956f45ee48c9d17b

Edit: here's the CNN feed I want to use: http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition_europe.rss

Comment: What's your question, and what have you tried?

Comment: I want to get that RSS feed from CNN replicated but with full images. URLs to full images are almost the same as those thumbnails but always end in "horizontal-gallery.jpg" and thumbnails end in "top-tease.jpg". That needs to be replaced

Comment: I tried the pipe like I linked it. Fetch Feed > Regex (in item.description, replace top-tease.jpg with horizontal-gallery.jpg) > Pipe Output

Comment: I just checked your RSS link to CNN and all the images are tiny so I don't really see what you expect... an RSS reader only uses data available in the RSS feed. It never tries to go read *a bigger picture* on the destination website.

Answer (score 0):

You can try replacing

```
([\w\d-]*)-top-tease\.(jpe?g|png)
```

with `$1-horizontal-gallery.$2`. This'll find png images as well, just in case.

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/wT0dY2/1).

Comment: Thank for your reply. I've done that replace but still shows the "top-tease.jpg" in the output. http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=d8562ff09578abb0956f45ee48c9d17b&_render=rss

Comment: Then we can assume that the problem isn't regex, but what you're doing with the pattern.

Comment: @user3379220: Not without knowing how you're using it. Are you using a greasemonkey script? A standalone program? Is it a feature of your feed reader?

Comment: I don't know. I only just discovered Yahoo Pipes and hoped it could do this for me